# Specified file not found Advanced Installer

Tags: windows-installer, installation, advanced-installer

I have created a 32/64 bit mixed installer package using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com).I am trying to implement chain installations by adding a .exe file to the current package under **Package Prerequisites**.It works fine on my windows 7 64bit PC ,but **when I run it on some other machine,it gives an error saying specified .exe file not found.**
I am not able to figure out what the possible reason could be

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: how do you add the prerequisite, as a file in package, download from URL? Also on what machines are you testing it?

Comment: file from disk @BogdanMitrache.I am testing it on both 32 and 64 bit windows 7 machine  as well as windows xp 32 bit machine.I am using a windows 7 machine and the installer works fine on my machine,But when i try running the installer on a 32bit machine I get the error File not found

Comment: Make sure that you have set the package to build a single EXE (with files included) as output, from Media page. This way the prerequisite should be included in your package and be available on all machines.